# Recommended approach for SPA authentication in Laravel 5.3

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jwt, laravel-5.3

I'm quit new to Laravel and read allready many tutorials about it. When it comes to authentication if I'm using Laravel as Backend and angularjs as my frontend I see there are multiple possibilities:

1. Laravel + tymo/jwt-auth plugin
2. Laravel + Dingo + tymo/jwt-auth
3. Since Laravel 5.3 using Passport directly

For now I'm confused about what's the right approach, and also if Passport is the reommended way to handle it, is there any tutorial for it in combination with angularjs 1.x?

What are the advantages of each approach over the others?

Thanks for clearing things out.

Greetings
eXe